# Featured filled corner css

Tags: html, css, joomla, font-awesome

I'm trying to add a triangle with a star in it at the corner of an article in Joomla.

This is my code:

Html

```
<div class="ribbon-wrapper-featured">
  <div class="ribbon-featured">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
/*corner ribbon*/
.ribbon-wrapper-featured {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.ribbon-featured {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 50px 50px 0;
    border-color: transparent #f1c40f transparent transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    _border-color: #000000 #f1c40f #000000 #000000;
    _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

But this is what I'm getting

[image]

I'm not very good in CSS so if you have a more efficient way to achieve this, it is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, using [Paulie-D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d)'s answer (Thanks!) and doing [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-41v6n3Vaf5s/UeRN_XJ0keI/AAAAAAAAN2Y/YxIHhddGiaw/s1600/css.gif). (Because copy-paste the answer didn't work)

HTML

```
<div class="ribbon-wrapper-featured"><div class="featured fa fa-star"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
/*corner ribbon*/
.ribbon-wrapper-featured {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    right: 0px;
}

.featured.fa {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: -30px;
}
.featured.fa::before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0;
    margin: .25em;
    color: gold;
    z-index: 2;
}
.featured::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: darkorange darkorange transparent transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: is a good idea to add a code snippet to this

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're trying to place a pseudo-element into a div with no height or width...so it won't fit.

If you position **two** pseudo-elements, the first being the Font Awesome `::before` and the second the triangle background I think you get more control.

You can swap out the icon, color it how you like and you also have control of the background independent of everything else.

Something like this:

```css
.featured.fa {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: block; /* needed to override FA styling */
  position: relative;
}
.featured.fa::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0;
  margin: .25em;
  color: gold;
}
.featured::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: darkorange darkorange transparent transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="featured fa fa-star"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**One class version with no extra html**, since you probably don't need to change the simbol.

**One scalable version** using same class name as above.

Both version using `linear-gradient`. Also `pointer-events: none;` would be a good addition.

```css
.card { height: 128px; }

.starred:before {
    font: normal normal normal 0.875rem/1 FontAwesome;
    content: "\f005";
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    padding: 0 0 1rem 1rem;
    background: linear-gradient(225deg, #28a745 50%, transparent 50%);
    color: #ffffff;
}
.starred.starred-left:before {
    left: 0px;
    right: unset;
    padding: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #dfdfdf 50%, transparent 50%);
}


/* scalable by font size */
.fa.featured {
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 2.857em;
    height: 2.857em;
    padding: 0.4em;
    background: linear-gradient(225deg, #dfdfdf 50%, transparent 50%);
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="m-4 p-4">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card starred starred-left"></div>
    <div class="card border-success starred"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <i class="featured fa fa-star"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```