# Adding a featured corner to panel heading in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a small triangle border in the panel corners of the panel headings.

I was able to add one using this example :

[Featured filled corner css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639846/featured-filled-corner-css?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I had to make minor changes to bring it to the left. But it only "kinda" works. It wont stick on changed resolutions though.

[image: This is how to looks when correct]

On changed resolutions it looks like this:

[image: Changed resolutions]

My Code for the Panel:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="ribbon-wrapper-featured">
                    <div class="featured fa"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">

                    <h3 class="panel-title">Select Activity Stream</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
  <style>
        /*corner ribbon*/
        .ribbon-wrapper-featured {
            position: absolute;
            top: -50px;
            right: 0px;
        }

        .featured.fa {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            right: 10px;
        }

            .featured.fa::before {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0%;
                top: 0;
                margin: .25em;
                color: gold;
                z-index: 2;
            }

        .featured::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            /* width: 0; */
            /* height: 0; */
            /* top: 0; */
            left: -38.4em;
            border-width: 20px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #03a9f4 transparent transparent #03a9f4;
            /* outline: auto; */
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .panel-title {
            background-color: #232323;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
            color: #03a9f4;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            padding: 0 20px 0 60px;
        }
    </style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to check against different resolutions, and there might be improvements possible on the triangle:

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 30px;
}
.panel-heading {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid blue;
    float: left;
}
h3 {
    line-height: 30px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
    <h3 class="panel-title">Select Activity Stream</h3>
</div>
```

Source for making triangles: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/